# É possivel setar resolução Câmera Android?

Tags: android, android-camera

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Android, e gostaria de saber se teria como fazer que a minha aplicação ao chamar a câmera passe os valores de resolução de Foto, ex: `1024 X 1024`?

Comment: É possível setar resolução para vídeo também?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nunca utilizei essa funcionalidade, mas já estudando outras funcionalidades da Câmera, vi que existia essa possibilidade.

Há um método em [`Camera.Parameters`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html), que se chama `setPictureSize (int width, int height)`, segue [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPictureSize(int,%20int)) da documentação da funcionalidade.

**Exemplo de implementação:**

```java
Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.set("jpeg-quality", 70);
parameters.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
parameters.setPictureSize(2048, 1232);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

> Obs¹: Você só deve usar tamanhos de imagem que estão disponíveis a partir de `getSupportedPictureSizes()`. Usar qualquer outra coisa pode travar o aplicativo.

```java
List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
```

> Obs²: Nunca utilizei está funcionalidade, mas na documentação diz que funciona.
>
> **Edit:** Segundo [@Gomes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/12048/gomes) isso funcionou para o caso.

Comment: Vou verificar aqui, e tentar fazer desta forma

Comment: @Gomes, não esqueça que você tem que utilizar uma resolução entre as que retornarem no método `getSupportedPictureSizes()`, pois pelo que vi se você utilizar algo fora disso o aplicativo vai dar _crash_.